# Git Hub pages website not reflecting behavior from localhost

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages

I have made a React web app and am hosting it through github pages, at [this link here](https://dakotamaker.github.io/resume-site/) and I have a header which directs you to different pages.

When the site is opened it should default to the home page and the header titled "Home" should be highlighted orange. When you select a link, then that link becomes orange (pretty straightforward). When running locally it runs fine and reacts how I would expect.

But on GitHub Pages, it does not default to any link being "selected" when you go directly to the site, or refresh, but behaves fine when you are selecting different links after the intial load.

The gif below visually demonstrates the issue. Localhost is on the right, the real page is on the left:

https://imgur.com/a/YMZ0Hm3

I am obviously trying to fix it, but would also like to know exactly what is causing the issue because this seems like quite the little issue.

The source code can be [found here](https://github.com/dakotamaker/resume-site).

The main routing code that is responsible is this section here from `headerComponent`

```
<Link onClick = {() => this.handleClick(Routes.HOME_PAGE) } className={this.state.url.toLowerCase() === Routes.HOME_PAGE.toLowerCase() ? 'selected':'nope'} to={Routes.HOME_PAGE}>Home</Link>
<Link onClick = {() => this.handleClick(Routes.RESUME_PAGE) } className={this.state.url.toLowerCase() === Routes.RESUME_PAGE.toLowerCase() ? 'selected':'nope'} to={Routes.RESUME_PAGE}>Resume</Link>   
<Link onClick = {() => this.handleClick(Routes.COVER_LETTER_PAGE) } className={this.state.url.toLowerCase() === Routes.COVER_LETTER_PAGE.toLowerCase() ? 'selected':'nope'} to={Routes.COVER_LETTER_PAGE}>Cover Letter</Link>
```

Where handleClick(route) just sets this.state.url to the route passed in

Comment: Could you include your React Router specific code in the question?

Comment: Instead of using the `Link` component, could you not use [`NavLink`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) instead, and set the [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) to `/resume-site` in production?

Comment: Can you show the value that you're setting to be the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue. In your state, you have:

```
this.state = {url: this.fullUrl.substr(this.fullUrl.lastIndexOf("/"), this.fullUrl.length - 1)};
```

This is cutting off everything except the last part of the url by default. So if the URL was `https://dakotamaker.github.io/resume-site/resume`, it would be setting state to `/resume`.

Then in your `<Link>`, you're checking if the url in state matches any of the routes. Assuming the `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` is `https://dakotamaker.github.io/resume-site/`, by on site load you're checking if `/`, `/resume`, `/coverLetter`, matches the full url equivalent. I.e.:

```
// before evaluation
className={this.state.url.toLowerCase() === Routes.HOME_PAGE.toLowerCase() ? 'selected':'nope'}

// after evaluation
className={'/resume' === 'https://dakotamaker.github.io/resume-site/resume' ? 'selected':'nope'}
```

But it works when you actually click on a link because your `.handleClick` function is setting the `url` in state to be the constant that you've defined in your Routes file. So if you click on the Resume page link, the `url` in state gets set to `Routes.RESUME_PAGE`. So when the Links check again whether it should add the class name, it's guaranteed that one link will always be selected.

So what you'll probably want to do is along the lines of not modifying the URL of the page the user first loads:

```
this.state = {url: this.fullUrl};
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your local website is on root of localhost:3000 but your github page is on the subdirectory. To fix that, you should put 'basename' props into your Router component. It should be some thing like this

```
<Router history={browserHistory} basename={'resume-site'}>
  <Route path="/" component={App} />
</Router>
```

I figured out that you have set your base name to env var. So just need to inject it while building by editing package.json:

```
 "deploy": "PUBLIC_URL=resume-site gh-pages -d build"
```